# Strider CD can't access environment variables in nodejs

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration

I'm using the strider-env plugin to create some environment variables for my application but I can't access them once it is deployed.

It is a Node.js application, I thought these variables would be added to process.env, but they aren't.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does your env file for strider look like?

Comment: I'm not using an env file, I'm setting the variables directly on strider

Comment: Seems like if you don't explicitly **export** the env vars you want to work system-wide, they are restricted to the strider process only. https://futurestud.io/tutorials/strider-configuration-guide-and-available-options

Comment: Yes that's what I thought, so it doesn't really fit my needs. For now I'm  exporting the variable before the command like NODE_ENV=testing pm2...

Comment: Yea, that definitely sucks...only thing you really can do is put those vars in the `package.json` command itself, which I'm sure is not ideal.

Comment: I just don't get why they call them env variables if they are restricted to the strider process.. That I can do directly in the bash.. Anyway, strider is cool and simple to use, but still green. Will continue using it until we release, if by then it hasn't improved I will switch to something more robust. Thanks for the help anyway :)